# How to deal with self-advertising posts?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44337/80) is on-topic, but the poster [fails to disclose that they are the author of the site.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/609/photoshop-animated-png/99851#99851)  [Stack Exchange policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/131640) discourages this.

What is the appropriate action in this case? The action I've taken is to clearly label the post as being self-advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

Using your privilege to edit the post seems appropriate. Leaving a comment would take more of your and the poster's time on following up on edits. If it's not a clear case or if it's a mild violation, then a friendly comment would do the job too.

Including [a link to the policy](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) would be important.

If a post is spammy, trying to get traffic to another site with little connection to the question asked, then "more drastic measures" are in order, don't know what those are...

Comment: You're correct!  It wasn't' a roll-back. My pre-coffee self was not awake. :-)